# Extract file name (without extension) while indexing using Data Import Handler in Solr

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4, apache-tika

Im successfully able to index pdf,doc,ppt,etc files using the Data Import Handler in solr 4.3.0 .

My data-config.xml looks like this -

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource name="bin" type="BinFileDataSource" />
    <document>
        <entity name="f" dataSource="null" rootEntity="false"
            processor="FileListEntityProcessor"
            baseDir="C:\Users\aroraarc\Desktop\Impdo" 
            fileName=".*\.(DOC)|(PDF)|(pdf)|(doc)|(docx)|(ppt)|(pptx)|(xls)|(xlsx)|(txt)" onError="skip"
            recursive="true">

            <field column="fileAbsolutePath" name="path" />
            <field column="fileSize" name="size" />
            <field column="fileLastModified" name="lastmodified" />
            <field column="file" name="fileName"/>

             <entity name="tika-test" dataSource="bin" processor="TikaEntityProcessor"
            url="${f.fileAbsolutePath}" format="text" onError="skip">
                <field column="Author" name="author" meta="true"/>
                <field column="title" name="title" meta="true"/>
                <field column="text" name="content"/>

          </entity>
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

However in the fileName field i want to insert the pure file name without the extension. Eg - Instead of 'HelloWorld.txt' I want only 'HelloWorld' to be inserted in the fileName field. How do I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [ScriptTransformer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#ScriptTransformer) to replace or change the value before it is indexed.

Example -

Data Config - Add custom field -

```
<script><![CDATA[
        function changeFileName(row){
            var fileName= row.get('fileName');
            // Replace or remove the extension .. e.g. from last index of . 
            file_name_new = file_name.replace ......
            row.put(fileName, row.get('file_name_new'));
            return row;
        }
]]></script>
```

Entity mapping -

```
<entity name="f" transformer="script:changeFileName" ....>
    ......
</entity>
```

Comment: What do i write in the query attribute?

Comment: ohk .. leave the query attribute its for DB calls. won't need it for file based DIH ...